# Android NDK: crash with GetIntArrayElements

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I suspect the GetIntArrayElements function of the jni ndk to crash sometimes
I used an array to send the list of touchscreen point to a native C function

```
tTouchPoint = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(tSrc, src, NULL);
```

and sometimes my galaxy Tab crash.
I can't be sure that the problem is due to this function. But it seem's that since I change the method to send touch point detection value, the problem has disappeared.

Does anybody used this king of function in the same context ?
That's to says at least 60 times per second ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

First argument of GetArrayElements is enviroment, and second is argument of variable.

So you need rewrite to:

```
tTouchPoint = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, src, NULL);
```